# How can I extract the content of a <tr> tag in PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing

i am new to regex. i would like to ask what would be the right combination for this html tag:

```
   <tr class="calendar_row" data-eventid="39654">
      <td class="alt1 eventDate smallfont" align="center"/></td>
      <td class="alt1 smallfont" align="center">3:34am</td>
      <td class="alt1 smallfont" align="center">CNY</td>
   </tr>
```

I am using this:

```
   $html = website html from a url
   $match = array();

   $pattern = "/(<tr.*?\data-eventid\>.*?<\/tr>)/ims";
   preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $match);
```

But it's not working :|
I just want to select all the content of that tr element..

Best Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Using DOMDocument

You shouldn't use regex on something like this; rather create a [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) from your markup and then select the children from that particular element. For instance, the following would give us the collective html of each `<td>` tag in your markup:

```php
// Our HTML will eventually go here
$innerHTML = "";

// Create a new DOMDocument based on our HTML
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->loadHTML($html);

// Get a NodeList of all <td> Elements
$cells = $document->getElementsByTagName("td");

// Cycle over each <td>, adding its HTML to $innerHTML
foreach ($cells as $cell) {
    $innerHTML .= $document->saveHTML($cell);
}

// Output our glorious HTML
echo $innerHTML;
```

#### Regular Expressions

If you really want to grab what is between the `tr` tags using `preg_match`, the following should work:

```php
// Our pattern for capturing all that is between <tr> and </tr>
$pattern = "/<tr[^>]*>(.*)<\/tr>/s";

// If a match is found, store the results in $match
if (preg_match($pattern, $html, $match)) {
    // Show the captured value
    echo $match[1];
}
```

Which results in the following:

```
<td class="alt1 eventDate smallfont" align="center"></td>
<td class="alt1 smallfont" align="center">3:34am</td>
<td class="alt1 smallfont" align="center">CNY</td>
```

Comment: @Vainglory07 I understand; but if you want to parse HTML you shouldn't do it with regular expressions, but rather by a much safer route of handling it as a document object.

Comment: :( i dont know..im sorry..Iam just studying an existing function from a past project..

Comment: @Vainglory07 I've updated the answer to share both approaches. Happy we could be helpful to you!